# How do I label the nth observation of a specific value in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 80,000+ rows. One of my columns has values that may repeat and I want to create a 'counter' column that marks each occurrence of the value as the nth occurrence. So if I am on row 10 and I see value = v1 and this is the third time that I have seen v1 so far, I want df.counter == 3. This is what I have so far

```
d = pd.DataFrame() # create empty df to append results to
for val in df.val_id.unique(): # loop through the unique val_id values
    f = pd.DataFrame(df.val_id[df.val_id == val]) # isolate all instances of specific val_id
    f['counter'] = range(1,len(f) + 1) # create counter column that labels each instance as the nth value
    d = pd.concat([d,f]) # append the result to my output df
```

I think this code works (haven't let the loop complete yet), but the problem is that this takes FOREVER. Timing one line of it takes 0.25 seconds so my estimate to complete this on my dataframe is over two hours.

There has to be a more pythonic/pandas-y/faster way to do this. Please help!

Comment: Do you mean something like `df['counter'] = df.groupby('val_id').cumcount() + 1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using `groupby` and `cumcount()` (*[details](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)*):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a']})
print(df)
```

Result:

```
 Col1
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
4    b
5    a
```

Now, using `cumcount()`:

```
df['Counter'] = df.groupby('Col1').cumcount()+1
print(df)
```

Result:

```
  Col1  Counter
0    a        1
1    b        1
2    c        1
3    a        2
4    b        2
5    a        3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with a loop:

Starting from a sample dataframe `df`:

```
  val_id
0     v1
1     v3
2     v2
3     v2
4     v1
5     v3
6     v3
7     v2
8     v3
9     v2
```

Go through this loop (it should be many times faster than your current loop)

```
for v in df.val_id.unique():
    df.loc[df.val_id.eq(v), 'counter'] =  df.val_id.eq(v).cumsum()
```

And your new `df` will look like this:

```
  val_id  counter
0     v1      1.0
1     v3      1.0
2     v2      1.0
3     v2      2.0
4     v1      2.0
5     v3      2.0
6     v3      3.0
7     v2      3.0
8     v3      4.0
9     v2      4.0
```

That being said, the `groupby` method posted in @AlexRiley's comment is *much* nicer and faster...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
In [49]: df
Out[49]: 
   D
0  a
1  b
2  a
3  c
4  b
5  a
6  c
7  c
8  b
9  b

In [50]: counters = df.groupby('D').apply(lambda x: np.arange(len(x)) + 1)

In [51]: df['counters'] = 0

In [52]: for label in counters.index:
    ...:     df.loc[df.D == label, 'counters'] = counters.loc[label]
    ...:     

In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
   D  counters
0  a         1
1  b         1
2  a         2
3  c         1
4  b         2
5  a         3
6  c         2
7  c         3
8  b         3
9  b         4
```